# Syntax error in Oracle create table query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Emp OF Emp_t(eno PRIMARY KEY, edept REFERENCES Dept);
```

There near the PRIMARY KEY, it will display a syntax error as expected not null. I need to solve it.

Below is the rest of queries in that schema.

```
CREATE TYPE Emp_t AS OBJECT(eno number(4),ename varchar2(15),edept ref dept_t,salary number(8,2));
/

CREATE TYPE Dept_t AS OBJECT(dno number(2),dname varchar2(12),mgr ref emp_t);
/

CREATE TYPE Proj_t AS OBJECT(pno number(4),pname varchar2(15),pdept ref dept_t,budget number(10,2));
/

CREATE TABLE Dept OF Dept_t(dno PRIMARY KEY,  mgr REFERENCES Emp);

CREATE TABLE Proj OF Proj_t(pno PRIMARY KEY, pdept REFERENCES dept);
```

Error is dispalyed as in the following image.
[image]

Comment: Are you able to create any of those tables, as they reference each other? (As do the types, so `dept_t` in valid immediately after creation, and has to be compiled, implicitly in this case by the `create table dept`, even if that fails).

Comment: First I could execute the all the type query statements. But then when try to execute create table it causes above error.

Comment: So couldn't be able to create any table. Only could create types

Comment: So what happens if you add `NOT NULL` before `PRIMARY KEY` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting that error - can you add the entire output you get when you try each of  the `create table` commands? You should be getting ORA-00942 as far as I can tell. Which version of Oracle DB are you using?

Comment: error remains same - Bozhidar

Comment: Oracel 12C. I have added snapshot of the error.  -  Alex

Comment: Maybe because the Emp table is referencing the Dept table that does not exist yet.  You have the Emp and Dept referencing each other.

Comment: Yeah. So how can I solve?

Comment: Create each table with just the primary key field.  Then issue an ALTER command to add in the REFERENCE for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LostInAlabama suggested, you can create the tables and add the circular constraints afterwards:

```
CREATE TABLE Dept OF Dept_t(dno PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Proj OF Proj_t(pno PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Emp OF Emp_t(eno PRIMARY KEY); 

ALTER TABLE Dept MODIFY (mgr REFERENCES Emp);
```

or preferably with named constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE Dept ADD (CONSTRAINT Dept_FK_Emp FOREIGN KEY (mgr) REFERENCES Emp);
ALTER TABLE Emp ADD (CONSTRAINT Emp_FK_Dept FOREIGN KEY (edept) REFERENCES Dept);
ALTER TABLE Proj ADD (CONSTRAINT Proj_FK_Dept FOREIGN KEY (pdept) REFERENCES Dept);
```